# Code is invoking an irrelevant web element

Tags: java, object, oop, methods, constructor

This is the XML file I'm executing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="PROJECT.Suite">
  <test name="PROJECT.Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testCases.ClickPrefPanel"/>
      <class name="testCases.Company_ExpandDepth_select"/>
      <class name="testCases.ClickOrgPanel"/>
      <class name="testCases.ClickReloadOrgBtn"/>
      <class name="testCases.ClickDivisionLevel"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- PROJECT.Test -->
</suite> <!-- PROJECT.Suite -->
```

My code is failing at this line:
`<class name="testCases.ClickReloadOrgBtn"/>`

This is the code of ClickReloadOrgBtn class:

```
package testCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pageObjects.OrgTreeObjects1;
import testBase.BaseClass;

public class ClickReloadOrgBtn extends BaseClass{
    
    @Test
    public void clickReloadBtn() {
        OrgTreeObjects1 org = new OrgTreeObjects1(driver);
        org.reloadBtn();
    }

}
```

According to the code; the code must go in the OrgTreeObjects1 class and click on the Reload Button. But instead it initializes this WebElement PracticeArea and gives me NoSuchElementException. Attaching only the relevant code of OrgTreeObjects1 class:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class OrgTreeObjects1 extends BasePage{

    public OrgTreeObjects1(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    
    /******************************************************************* Locators ******************************************************************/
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='westPanel']//div[@id='westPanel-body']//a[@data-qtip='Reload']//*[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon-el')]")
    WebElement ReloadOrgBtn;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='OrgTree-bodyWrap']/div[@id='OrgTree-body']/div[@aria-valuetext='Loading...']//div[text()='Loading...']"
            + "//ancestor::div[@aria-valuetext='Loading...']//preceding-sibling::div[contains(@class,'x-masked') and @aria-busy='true']") // WebElement of Loading Element in Org Tree after clicking Reload button
    WebElement OrgTreeLoadingBox;
    
    String division = "//*[@class='x-grid-item-container']//span[normalize-space()='"+bundle.getString("Division")+"']";
    WebElement Division = driver.findElement(By.xpath(division));
    WebElement ExpandDivision = driver.findElement(By.xpath(division+"//parent::div//div[contains(@class,'expander')]"));
    
    String practiceArea = "//span[normalize-space()='"+bundle.getString("PracticeArea")+"']";
    WebElement PracticeArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath(practiceArea+"//ancestor::table//following-sibling::table//span[normalize-space()='"+bundle.getString("PracticeArea")+"']"));
    
    /******************************************************************* Actions ******************************************************************/
    
    public void reloadBtn() {
        w2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ReloadOrgBtn)).click();
        log.info("Reload button on Org Tree is clicked");
        if(w2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(OrgTreeLoadingBox)).isDisplayed()) {
            w5.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(OrgTreeLoadingBox));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried commenting the WebElement PracticeArea line and then the code works fine. I expected that I might get the same error for WebElement Division, considering the same syntax. But I'm not getting the error there. I'm not understanding why.

I understand when we create an instance of object, its members get initialized. But then why is the Division WebElement not getting initialized? I'm not understanding that. I'm stuck on this issue since two days.

I tried putting the Web element in a method, then returning the web element from the method and assigning it to the web element. But it didn't work as well. Attaching the code:

```
WebElement PracticeArea = getPracticeArea(driver);
private WebElement getPracticeArea(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(PracticeArea+"//ancestor::table//following-sibling::table//span[normalize-space()='"+bundle.getString("PracticeArea")+"']"));
    }
```